# Why in Ephesians 1:15 is Paul saying that he heard of Ephesian’s faith?

Tags: paul, ephesians, context

Why is Paul referring to Ephesian’s faith as something he heard of

> Wherefore I also, after I heard of your faith in the Lord Jesus, and love unto all the saints, Cease not to give thanks for you, making mention of you in my prayers; That the God of our Lord Jesus Christ, the Father of glory, may give unto you the spirit of wisdom and revelation in the knowledge of him: [Ephesians 1:15-17 KJV]

Comment: What makes you think he wouldn't have heard of their faith? Please explain.

Answer (score 1):

> Acts 20:17 From **Miletus**, Paul sent to **Ephesus** for the **elders** of the church. 18When they arrived, he said to them: “You know how I lived the whole time I was with you, from the first day I came into the province of Asia.

Paul was in Ephesus and taught the church there. He left and the Ephesian church elders later met him in Miletus, about 80 km from Ephesus.

> 19 I served the Lord with great humility and with tears and in the midst of severe testing by the plots of my Jewish opponents. 20You know that I have not hesitated to preach anything that would be helpful to you but have **taught** you publicly and from house to house. 21I have declared to both Jews and Greeks that they must turn to God in repentance and have faith in our Lord Jesus.

> 22“And now, compelled by the Spirit, I am going to Jerusalem, ...
> 25“Now I know that **none of you** among whom I have gone about preaching the kingdom **will ever see me again**.

Paul would not see them again.

> 36 When Paul had finished speaking, he knelt down with all of them and prayed. 37They all wept as they embraced him and kissed him. 38What grieved them most was his statement that **they would never see his face again**. Then they accompanied him to the ship.

Some years later, Paul wrote them a letter:

> Ephesians 1:15
> For this reason, ever since **I heard about your faith** in the Lord Jesus and your love for all God's people,

Pulpit Commentary expressed a similar sentiment.

> though he [Paul] derived his first acquaintance from personal intercourse, it was some years since he had been at Ephesus, and the ἀκούσας refers to what he had heard in the interval.

Paul taught the Ephesian congregation personally. Left the church to head for Jerusalem. On the way, he met the Ephesian elders in Miletus. They exchanged information. Paul never saw them again. Meanwhile, he learned of their spiritual progress and wrote them a letter mentioning the good faith that he heard of them as an encouragement.